# Unity grappling more like Tarzan

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a grappling hook more fluent but as of right now it is very choppy and does not have the right feel. It currently makes a line and pulls the player there. I have not tried anything yet because I am not even sure we're to start on fixing this. Here is all the grappling code below. `using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(SFPSC_PlayerMovement))] // PlayerMovement also requires Rigidbody
public class SFPSC_GrapplingHook : MonoBehaviour
{
public bool IsGrappling
{
get { return isGrappling; }
}

```
private SFPSC_PlayerMovement pm;
private Rigidbody rb;
private int segments;
private void Start()
{
    segments = rope.segments;
    pm = this.GetComponent<SFPSC_PlayerMovement>();
    rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private bool isGrappling = false;
private void Update()
{
    if (crossHairSpinningPart != null)
    {
        // we need 2 raycasts bc w/ 1 you can grapple through colliders which isn't good
        if (Physics.Raycast(SFPSC_FPSCamera.cam.transform.position, SFPSC_FPSCamera.cam.transform.forward, out hitInfo, maxGrappleDistance, layerMask))
        {
            hitName = hitInfo.collider.name;
            if (Physics.Raycast(SFPSC_FPSCamera.cam.transform.position, SFPSC_FPSCamera.cam.transform.forward, out hitInfo, maxGrappleDistance))
            {
                if (hitName != hitInfo.collider.name)
                    goto _else;
                crossHairSpinningPart.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                crossHairSpinningPart.Rotate(Vector3.forward * crossHairSpinSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                goto _out;
            }
        }

        _else:
        crossHairSpinningPart.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    _out:

    if (!isGrappling)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(SFPSC_KeyManager.Grapple))
            Grapple();
        
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!Input.GetKey(SFPSC_KeyManager.Grapple))
            UnGrapple();
        GrappleUpdate();

        return;
    }
}

[Header("Properties")]
public float maxGrappleDistance = 100.0f;
public SFPSC_Rope rope;
public float maximumSpeed = 100.0f;
public float deceleration = 2500.0f; // This is how much the player is going to decelerate after stopped grappling
public float deceleratingTime = 1.4f; // This is the time the decelerating is going to act on the player after stopped grappling
public RectTransform crossHairSpinningPart;
public float crossHairSpinSpeed = 200.0f;
public float distanceToStop = 2.0f;
public LayerMask layerMask;
public float grappleCooldown = 1.0f;
private bool isBlocked = false;

private Transform location; // the grappled location
private RaycastHit hitInfo;
private string hitName;
public void Grapple()
{
    if (isBlocked)
        return;

    // we need 2 raycasts bc w/ 1 you can grapple through colliders which isn't good
    if (Physics.Raycast(SFPSC_FPSCamera.cam.transform.position, SFPSC_FPSCamera.cam.transform.forward, out hitInfo, maxGrappleDistance, layerMask))
    {
        hitName = hitInfo.collider.name;
        if (Physics.Raycast(SFPSC_FPSCamera.cam.transform.position, SFPSC_FPSCamera.cam.transform.forward, out hitInfo, maxGrappleDistance))
        {
            if (hitName != hitInfo.collider.name)
                return;
            // We create a GameObject and we parent it to the grappled object. 
            // If we don't parent it to the object and the object moves the player is stuck only on one location instead of the moving object.
            location = new GameObject().transform;//Instantiate(new GameObject(), hitInfo.point, Quaternion.identity).transform;
            location.position = hitInfo.point;
            location.parent = hitInfo.collider.transform;

            if (decelerateTimer != 0.0f)
                StopCoroutine(Decelerate());
            pm.DisableMovement();
            // Rope attaching
            rope.segments = (int)((hitInfo.distance / maxGrappleDistance) * segments);
            rope.Grapple(transform.position, hitInfo.point);

            rb.useGravity = false;
            isGrappling = true;
        }
    }
}

private Vector3 grappleForce;
public void UnGrapple()
{
    if (!isGrappling)
        return;
    if (location != null)
        Destroy(location.gameObject);
    if (decelerateTimer == 0.0f)
        StartCoroutine(Decelerate());
    else
        decelerateTimer = 0.0f;

    pm.EnableMovement();
    // Rope detaching
    rope.UnGrapple();

    Invoke("UnblockGrapple", grappleCooldown);
    
    rb.useGravity = true;
    isGrappling = false;
}

private void UnblockGrapple()
{
    isBlocked = false;
}

private float decelerateTimer = 0.0f, max;
private IEnumerator Decelerate()
{
    WaitForEndOfFrame wfeof = new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    max = deceleratingTime * Mathf.Clamp01(targetDistance / 10.0f) * Mathf.Clamp01(rb.velocity.magnitude / 30.0f);
    for (; decelerateTimer < max; decelerateTimer += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        rb.AddForce(-rb.velocity.normalized * deceleration * (1.0f - decelerateTimer / max) * Mathf.Clamp01(rb.velocity.sqrMagnitude / 400.0f) * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        yield return wfeof;
    }
    decelerateTimer = 0.0f;
}

private Vector3 dir;

private float speed = 0.0f, targetDistance;
private void GrappleUpdate()
{
    if (location == null)
        return;
    
    targetDistance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, location.position);
    rope.segments = (int)((targetDistance / maxGrappleDistance) * segments);
    dir = (location.position - transform.position).normalized;
    
    rb.velocity = Vector3.Lerp(rb.velocity, dir * maximumSpeed * Mathf.Clamp01(targetDistance / (4.0f * distanceToStop)), Time.deltaTime);

    // Rope updating
    rope.UpdateStart(transform.position);
    rope.UpdateGrapple();
}

private Vector3 ClampMag(Vector3 vec, float maxMag)
{
    if (vec.sqrMagnitude > maxMag * maxMag)
        vec = vec.normalized * maxMag;
    return vec;
}
```

}
`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `FixedUpdate` instead of `Update` for physics based work (basically all of your code in Update right now). Update is dependent on your computer's clock speed and refresh rate (more or less), and gets called at fairly irregular intervals, because the next update is called in the next frame, after the present frame has finished processing. `FixedUpdate` makes it frame-rate independent.

Also, you can cap your framerate using `Application.targetFrameRate` and cap it to a decent FPS.

You could also multiply your movement with `Time.deltaTime` for smoother movement, although this is a standard practice and yet debatable for use as a smoothing value.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate a hinge joint when grappling at the location of the raycast hit https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-HingeJoint2D.html